# How to display a button for specific image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a little problem. My client would like to add button to their slides when the user is on the mobile version of the site which wouldn't be a problem to do.

However, they do not recall the folder the holds the slides in the CMS. So I look through and could not find those slides myself.

So my question is: What would be a good approach to determine which button belongs to which slides?

Comment: What framework is the site built around? Also, not really sure what you mean by slides. How do they access their CMS?

Comment: @Adjit They are using Mura. The previous developer used jquery, ColdFusion, css and html. They have access to build pages, add meta tags and so on. What I mean by slide, they have a carousel on their homepage. Each carousel has a button that pertains to it